# SharePoint/MS Lists Calculated Column text to number wont work

Tags: list, calculated-column, error, mslists

I'm starting to get desperate so any help is appreciated!

I want my choice column [Team Name] be read and then a dynamic answer in the form of a number has to be returned. To keep it simple, I want when `[Team Name] = "Team Rocket"`, the value returned to be 1, and if not, the value returned can be 2.

I've tried many variants of the following, only thing I know for sure I that I have to use ; and not ,(comma).

**Note**: I am using the return number option.

Below all give syntax errors:

```
=IF([Team Name]="Team Rocket";1;2)

=IF([Team Name]="Team Rocket",1,2)

=IF([Team Name]="Team Rocket";"1";"2")
```

[image]

Comment: Is your choice column Single selection or multiple selection column?